# hiding imagebutton1 on click then show imagebutton2

Tags: android

i have 2 image buttons.
imagebutton & imagebutton2  , i have place them both 1 on top another and setted imagebutton2 to ( invisible ).

my goal is to click imagebutton1 then hide imagebutton1 and show imagebutton2.

here is the code i have

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                         p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                         camera.setParameters(p);
                       camera.stopPreview();
                        isLighOn = false;
                    findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offf);
                    //    imageButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });



            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLighOn = true;
                    // imageButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onn);
                    // ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                    //  btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.onn);

                    //findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onn);


                }

            });
```

these code below

```
imageButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imageButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

crashes my app when i click it

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageView`s are null when you are accessing them.
You need to initialize them before using:

```
imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

Comment: I have wasted 8 man hours and you solved me problem in 1 minute thanks man.

Comment: No problems. Please mark this answer as correct if it helped.